# How to SKEW IMAGE in P5JS and place that images pixels in another image's pixel

Tags: javascript, simulation, p5.js

I have been searching for a while but was not able to find any about image skewing with p5.js.
I am working on a wall painting simulation where I have to make the wall and replace it with other image. I have marked the pixels in the images where the wall is making it RGBA(0,0,0,0) for the pixels and a quad to mark the space where the wallpaper will be painted.
[Github of the js file](https://github.com/peeyalk/Hakase/blob/master/wwwroot/js/paint.js)

Before :
[image]
After Marking and selecting the area for the wallpaper:
[image]
This marking is done by implementing flood fill effect and converting the pixels to black.

now the problem is i dont know how to skew the image.
I tried to rotate the image but its not what i am looking for.
Any kind of suggestion will be greatly appreciated. I am in a total deadlock.

Comment: Don't just tag your post with every single tag. If you're using p5js, _don't_ tag it as processing, and _certainly_ don't tag it as processing.js

Comment: The theory behind all of them remains the same as far as i knew.